# SwiftUI CalendarView decoration bug? calendar updating but the badge stays there

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

When I update/change entry's date calendar updating, but the decoration dot stays in the past date and new updated date at the same time.
you can watch video and will realize it quickly

[The Problem's short video](https://www.veed.io/view/8e132ea9-261c-4b1e-bde7-0aa2f80ecee6?panel=share)

CalendarElementView.swift

```
struct CalendarElementView : UIViewRepresentable{
    
    let interval : DateInterval
    @ObservedObject var entryStore = DataController.shared
    @Binding var dateSelected : DateComponents?
    @Binding var displayEvents : Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        let view = UICalendarView()
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        view.availableDateRange = interval
        
        //to select a date to see entries
        let dateSelection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: context.coordinator)
        view.selectionBehavior = dateSelection
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICalendarView, context: Context) {
        
        if let changedEntry = entryStore.changedEntry {

            uiView.reloadDecorations(forDateComponents: [changedEntry.dateComponents], animated: true)
            Task{
                entryStore.changedEntry = nil
            }
        }

        if let movedEntry = entryStore.movedEntry {
            uiView.reloadDecorations(forDateComponents: [movedEntry.dateComponents], animated: true)
            Task{
                entryStore.movedEntry = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self,entryStore:_entryStore)
    }
    
    class Coordinator :NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate, UICalendarSelectionSingleDateDelegate {
        
        func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, didSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) {
            
            guard let dateComponents else { return }
            parent.dateSelected = dateComponents
            
            let foundEntries = parent.entryStore.savedEntries
                .filter {
                    $0.date?.startOfDay == dateComponents.date?.startOfDay
                }
            
            if !foundEntries.isEmpty {
                parent.displayEvents.toggle()
            }
            
            
            
        }
        func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, canSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        
        var parent : CalendarElementView
        //@ObservedObject var eventStore: EventStore
        @ObservedObject var entryStore: DataController

        init(parent: CalendarElementView,entryStore:ObservedObject<DataController>) {
            self.parent = parent
            self._entryStore = entryStore
        }
        
        @MainActor
        func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {

            let foundEntries = parent.entryStore.savedEntries
                .filter {
                    $0.date?.startOfDay == dateComponents.date?.startOfDay
                }
            
            
            if foundEntries.isEmpty { return nil }
            
            if foundEntries.count > 1 {
                return .image(UIImage(systemName: "circlebadge.2.fill"), color:.systemBlue,size: .medium)
            }
            
        
            return .image(UIImage(systemName: "circlebadge.fill"),color:.systemBlue,size:.medium)

            
 
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

DataController.swift

```
class DataController : ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = DataController()
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Diary")
    @Published var savedEntries : [Entry] = []
    @Published var cache = NSCache<NSString, DiaryEntry>()
    @Published var changedEntry: Entry?
    @Published var movedEntry: Entry?
    
    

    init(inMemory: Bool = false){
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores { desc, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Failed to load data \(error.localizedDescription)")
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        fetchEntries()
        print("DataController initialized")
    }
    
    deinit{
        print("DataController deinitialized")
    }
    
    //first fetching
    func fetchEntries() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            //to save self from optional we write this
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
            do {
                let entries = try self.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
                //when background complete
                //Update UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.savedEntries = entries
                    print("Entries loaded")
                    
                    for savedEntry in self.savedEntries {
                        print(savedEntry.title ?? "empty")
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }catch let error {
                print("Error fetching. \(error)")
                let fatalErr = error as NSError
                fatalError(fatalErr.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateAndSaveEntries(){
        fetchEntries()
        save(context: container.viewContext)
    }
    
    
    func save(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                try context.save()
            }catch {
                let error = error as NSError
                print("Error couldn't save data")
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Entries
    func addEntry(title:String, entry:String, mood:moodsList,date:Date, context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let newEntry = Entry(context: context)
        newEntry.id = UUID()
        newEntry.date = date
        newEntry.title = title
        newEntry.entry = entry
        newEntry.mood = mood.entryMood
        self.save(context: context)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.savedEntries.append(newEntry)
            //new added
            self.changedEntry = newEntry
            print("New Entry added")
            for savedEntry in self.savedEntries {
                print(savedEntry.title ?? "empty")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //Updating Function
    func editUpdateEntryNew(entry:Entry,newDate:Date,newTitle:String,newEntry:String,newMood:moodsList){
        
        if let index = savedEntries.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == entry.id }) {
                let updatedEntry = savedEntries[index]
                updatedEntry.title = newTitle
                updatedEntry.date = newDate
                updatedEntry.entry = newEntry
                updatedEntry.mood = newMood.entryMood

                // Save the context to persist the changes
                save(context: container.viewContext)

                // Update the changedEntry and movedEntry properties
                self.changedEntry = updatedEntry
                self.movedEntry = updatedEntry
            }
        
        
    }
```

CalendarView.Swift

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    @State private var dateSelected:DateComponents?
    @State private var displayEvents = false 
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                CalendarElementView(
                    interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: .distantFuture), dateSelected: $dateSelected, displayEvents: $displayEvents
                )
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $displayEvents, content: {
                CalendarItemSheetView(dateSelected: $dateSelected)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium,.large])
            })
            .onAppear {
                print("CalendarElementView appeared")
                    
            }
            .navigationTitle("Calendar")
        }
        
    }
}
```

CalendarItemSheetView.swift

```
struct CalendarItemSheetView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var entryStore : DataController
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: EntryViewModel
    @Binding var dateSelected : DateComponents?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                if let dateSelected {
                    let foundEntries = entryStore.savedEntries
                        .filter {
                            $0.date?.startOfDay == dateSelected.date?.startOfDay
                        }
                    List{
                        ForEach(foundEntries) { entry in
                            let day = entry.date? .formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted).description
                            NavigationLink {
                                DiaryEntryDetailView(diaryEntry: entry)
                                    .navigationTitle(entry.title ?? "Diary Note")
                            } label: {
                                HStack{
                                    viewModel.getImageByPoint(point: entry.mood).resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    Text(entry.title ?? "ERROR")
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(day ?? "ERROR")
                                }
                            }
                            .swipeActions {
                                Button {
                                    entryStore.deleteEntryByEntry(context: entryStore.container.viewContext, entry: entry)
                                } label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                }.tint(.red)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }.navigationTitle(dateSelected.date?.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted) ?? "")
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

DiaryEntryDetailView.swift

```
struct DiaryEntryDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: EntryViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController : DataController
    @State private var isEditMode = false
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    let diaryEntry: FetchedResults<Entry>.Element
    
    @State private var newTitle = ""
    @State private var newEntry = ""
    @State private var currentMood = moodsList.excellent
    @State private var currentDate = Date.now
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List{
                if isEditMode {
                    Section("Update Title") {
                        TextField("", text: $newTitle)
                            .onAppear {
                                newTitle = diaryEntry.title ?? ""
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    Section("Title") {
                        Text(diaryEntry.title ?? "EMPTY")
                    }
                    }
            
                if isEditMode {
                    Section("Update Mood") {
                        Picker("", selection: $currentMood) {
                            ForEach(moodsList.allCases, id: \.self) { mood in
                                viewModel.getImageMood(mood: mood,isPNG: false)
                            }
                        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .background(Color.clear)
                            .onAppear {
                                currentMood = viewModel.getEnumByPoint(point: diaryEntry.mood )
                            }
                    }
                
                } else {
                    Section("Mood") {
                        HStack {
                            viewModel.getImageByPoint(point: diaryEntry.mood )
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            Text(diaryEntry.mood.description)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            
            
           
                if isEditMode {
                    Section("Update Diary Note") {
                        TextEditor(text: $newEntry)
                            .onAppear {
                                newEntry = diaryEntry.entry ?? ""
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    Section("Diary Note") {
                        Text(diaryEntry.entry ?? "EMPTY")
                    }
                }
            
            
            Section("Created Date") {
                if let date = diaryEntry.date?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time:.shortened) {
                    Text(date.description)
                }
            }
            
            DatePicker(selection: $currentDate) {
                Text("Update Date and Time")
            }
            
           
            isEditing ?
            Button(action: {
                
                dataController.editUpdateEntryNew(entry: diaryEntry,newDate:currentDate,newTitle:newTitle,newEntry:newEntry,newMood:currentMood)
                isEditMode = false
                isEditing = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            })
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            
            : nil
            
            
            
            
            
        }.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                
                if isEditMode {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        isEditMode.toggle()
                        isEditing.toggle()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    .tint(.red)
                } else {
                    Button("Edit") {
                        isEditMode.toggle()
                        isEditing.toggle()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    .tint(.blue)
                }
            }
                
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            currentDate = diaryEntry.date ?? .now
            
            print(diaryEntry.dateComponents.description)
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I have tried to use @FetchRequest in CalendarElementView.swift it didn't work as well, when I update any entry's date on calendar, it updates calendar but in the past date still showing the decoration badge..